# Carotenoid biosynthesis in yeast

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, bioinformatics, enzymes, yeast

Does Budding Yeast Sacchromyces cerevisiae produces significant amount of carotenoids?
Have anybody estimated the ratio of flux going in branches 1. Cholesterol synthesis(via squalene)
2. Coenzyme Q6 and 3. Dolichols Glycoprotein and others from the branch point of Farnesyl diphosphate.

Here is the kegg pathway

http://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/show_pathway?map00900
I also have pathway formatted but couldn't upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enzyme phytoene synthase is the first committed step in carotenoid biosynthesis. *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* doesn't have this enzyme, nor does it have the rest of the relevant pathway. Other yeasts such as *Rhodotorula spp* and *Phaffia rhodozyma* can make carotenoids.

However, [carotenoid biosynthesis has been engineered into *S. cerevisiae*](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21573686).

Comment: what about the distribution of fluxex from Farnesyl